# RPC failure code 14 in our simple GRPC example program

Tags: c++, linux, grpc

We've made good progress in getting GRPC running under RHEL 7.
Our application has one rather complicated structure with three levels of nesting with the outer level implementing a "oneof" keyword.
We find that all our other structures run fine, but this one gives us an RPC failure with code=14.
We've simplified this part of the application as much as possible so it can hopefully be recompiled and run easily.

Here's the .proto file, updated to accommodate Uli's question:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "io.grpc.examples.debug";
option java_outer_classname = "DebugProto";
option objc_class_prefix = "DEBUG";

package DEBUGpackage;

service DEBUGservice {
  rpc DEBUG_val_container_get (input_int32_request) returns (outer_container) {}
}

message input_int32_request {
  int32 ival = 1;
}

message inner_container {
  repeated uint32 val_array = 1;
}

message middle_container {
  inner_container    vac = 1;
}

message other_container {
  int32 other_val = 1;
}

message outer_container {
  oneof reply {
    middle_container   r1 = 1;
    other_container    r2 = 2;
  }
}
```

(Please note that the java lines in this prototype code are just in there because they are in the GRPC website examples. Our code is entirely C++, with no java. Don't know if that means we can do without some of these "option java..." lines).

Here's our client source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <grpc++/grpc++.h>
#include <grpc/support/log.h>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "debug.grpc.pb.h"

using grpc::Channel;
using grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReader;
using grpc::ClientContext;
using grpc::CompletionQueue;
using grpc::Status;
using DEBUGpackage::input_int32_request;
using DEBUGpackage::inner_container; 
using DEBUGpackage::middle_container; 
using DEBUGpackage::outer_container;
using DEBUGpackage::DEBUGservice;

class DEBUGClient {
  public:

    explicit DEBUGClient(std::shared_ptr<Channel> channel)
            : stub_(DEBUGservice::NewStub(channel)) {}

    void DEBUG_val_container_get() {
        std::cout << "in DEBUG_val_container_get" << std::endl;
        // Data we are sending to the server
        input_int32_request val;
        val.set_ival(0);
        AsyncClientCall* call = new AsyncClientCall;
        call->response_reader = stub_->AsyncDEBUG_val_container_get(&call->context, val, &cq_);
        call->response_reader->Finish(&call->reply_, &call->status, (void*)call);

    }

    void AsyncCompleteRpc() {
        void* got_tag;
        bool ok = false;

        while (cq_.Next(&got_tag, &ok)) {
            AsyncClientCall* call = static_cast<AsyncClientCall*>(got_tag);
            GPR_ASSERT(ok);
            if (call->status.ok()) {
                if (call->reply_.has_r1()) {
                   std::cout << call << " DEBUG received: " 
                             << call->reply_.r1().vac().val_array(0) << std::endl;
                }
            }
            else {
                std::cout << call << " RPC failed" << std::endl;
                std::cout << " RPC failure code = " << call->status.error_code() << std::endl;
                std::cout << " RPC failure message = " << call->status.error_message() << std::endl;
            }
            delete call;
        }
    }

  private:
    struct AsyncClientCall {
        outer_container reply_;
        ClientContext context;
        Status status;
        std::unique_ptr<ClientAsyncResponseReader<outer_container>> response_reader;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<DEBUGservice::Stub> stub_;
    CompletionQueue cq_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    DEBUGClient DEBUG0(grpc::CreateChannel("172.16.17.46:50050", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()));
    std::thread thread0_ = std::thread(&DEBUGClient::AsyncCompleteRpc, &DEBUG0);
    DEBUG0.DEBUG_val_container_get();
    sleep(1);
    std::cout << "Press control-c to quit" << std::endl << std::endl;
    thread0_.join();  //blocks forever
    return 0;
}
```

And, here's our server source code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#include <grpc++/grpc++.h>
#include <grpc/support/log.h>

#include "debug.grpc.pb.h"

#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using grpc::Server;
using grpc::ServerAsyncResponseWriter;
using grpc::ServerBuilder;
using grpc::ServerContext;
using grpc::ServerCompletionQueue;
using grpc::Status;
using DEBUGpackage::inner_container;
using DEBUGpackage::input_int32_request;
using DEBUGpackage::middle_container;
using DEBUGpackage::outer_container;
using DEBUGpackage::DEBUGservice;

std::string save_server_address;

class ServerImpl final {

  public:

    ~ServerImpl() {
      server_->Shutdown();
      cq_->Shutdown();
    }

    void Run() {
      std::string server_address("0.0.0.0:50050");
      ServerBuilder builder;
      builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
      builder.RegisterService(&service_);
      cq_ = builder.AddCompletionQueue();
      server_ = builder.BuildAndStart();
      std::cout << "Server listening on " << server_address << std::endl;
      save_server_address = server_address;
      HandleRpcs();
    }

  private:

    class CallData {
      public:
        virtual void Proceed() = 0;
    };

    class DebugGetCallData final : public CallData{

      public:

        DebugGetCallData(DEBUGservice::AsyncService* service, ServerCompletionQueue* cq)
            : service_(service), cq_(cq), responder_(&ctx_), status_(CREATE) {
          Proceed();
        }
        void Proceed() {
          if (status_ == CREATE) {
            status_ = PROCESS;
            service_->RequestDEBUG_val_container_get(&ctx_, &request_, &responder_, cq_, cq_, this);
          } else if (status_ == PROCESS) {
            new DebugGetCallData(service_, cq_);
            char *portchar;
            portchar = (char *) save_server_address.c_str();
            long cq_addr = (long) cq_;
            int cq_addr32 = (int) (cq_addr & 0xfffffff);
            srand(cq_addr32);
            fprintf(stderr, "%s task started\n", portchar); fflush(stderr);
            unsigned int return_val = 10;
            inner_container ic;
            ic.add_val_array(return_val);
            middle_container reply_temp;
            reply_temp.set_allocated_vac(&ic);
            reply_.set_allocated_r1(&reply_temp);
            fprintf(stderr, "%s %s task done\n", portchar, "val_container_get"); fflush(stderr);
            status_ = FINISH;
            responder_.Finish(reply_, Status::OK, this);
          } else {
            GPR_ASSERT(status_ == FINISH);
          }
        }

      private:

        DEBUGservice::AsyncService* service_;
        ServerCompletionQueue* cq_;
        ServerContext ctx_;
        input_int32_request request_;
        outer_container reply_;
        ServerAsyncResponseWriter<outer_container> responder_;
        enum CallStatus { CREATE, PROCESS, FINISH };
        CallStatus status_;
    };

    void HandleRpcs() {
      new DebugGetCallData(&service_, cq_.get());
      void* tag;
      bool ok;
      while (true) {
        GPR_ASSERT(cq_->Next(&tag, &ok));
        GPR_ASSERT(ok);
        static_cast<CallData*>(tag)->Proceed();
      }
    }

    std::unique_ptr<ServerCompletionQueue> cq_;
    DEBUGservice::AsyncService service_;
    std::unique_ptr<Server> server_;
};

int main() {
    ServerImpl server;
    server.Run();
    return 0;
}
```

The output when I run it looks like this:

```
[fossum@netsres46 debug]$ DEBUG_client2
in DEBUG_val_container_get
0xb73ff0 RPC failed
 RPC failure code = 14
 RPC failure message = Endpoint read failed
Press control-c to quit
```

We ran the server under gdb, and found a place in the generated
file "debug.pb.cc" where if we just comment out one line, it all starts working.

Here's the pertinent piece of the generated file "debug.pb.cc":

```
middle_container::~middle_container() {
  // @@protoc_insertion_point(destructor:DEBUGpackage.middle_container)
  SharedDtor();
}

void middle_container::SharedDtor() {
  if (this != internal_default_instance()) {
    delete vac_; // comment out this one line, to make the problem go away
  }
}
```

The "delete vac_" line appears to be an attempt to delete storage that either has already been deleted, or is about to be deleted somewhere else.  Please, can someone look into this?  [The files below are still the files we use to generate this code, and to debug the problem to this point]

I have no idea whether I've uncovered a bug in GRPC, or whether I've coded something wrong.

Comment: What happens when you actually put more than one sub-type in your oneof? RIght now it's not much of a oneof.

Comment: @uli

Thanks for the quick reply!  I've added another sub-type, and the behavior was the same.  I also added the printout of the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: Ok. I don't know about the grpc C implementation, unfortunately. Is there any more info about error code 14 on the grpc.io website or at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/doc ? I seem to recall a few documents with error codes. If you don't get a reply here, perhaps someone on the grpc Google Group can help.

Comment: I have seen notes warning me to not post problems on multiple groups, as that would tag me as somehow a bad person.  So, I'm hesitant to add this question in other places.  I guess I was hoping that someone could take my code and run it, and see if they got the same problem.  If they do, then either they can point out what is wrong in my code, or they can maybe let me know that it looks like a bug in GRPC which will be investigated...  I tried really hard to make this test case as simple as possible for that reason...

Comment: I just discovered that if I run our server code on our Ubuntu machine, the problem doesn't appear.  So, this seems to be specific to server code running on RHEL 7.  I don't know if this makes you more or less interested, but in the interest of clarity, I figured I should let you know...

Comment: With my "fix" (commenting out some "delete" lines in the generated code), I can now run on both RHEL 7 and Ubuntu flawlessly, each client accessing servers on both boxes simultaneously.  I very much would like to know if this is a bug in gRPC, or if my source code has something wrong with it...

Comment: Thanks for following up. If you've found a solution, please use the answer section below rather than adding "UPDATE" to the post. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/ ; https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202472/ We don't do things like they're done in forums.

Comment: I don't call it a solution.  One should not have to edit the generated code, as I do in my "workaround." I'm making the claim that this is evidence of some bug in GRPC, because in this particular case "someone" is trying to do two "deletes" on a single message.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are allocated `middle_container reply_tmp` on the stack in your server. As a result it gets destructed as soon as you pass out of the scope. At that time, you have called `Finish` but not yet waited for its result. Since this is an async server, the data must remain alive until you've received the tag back for it. This is why manually editing your destructor works in your case; you're basically nullifying the destructor (and leaking memory as a result).

Comment: @VijayPai Thank you for this.  

I'm a bit weak on this whole "waiting for the result of the Finish" thing.  
Our code was based on the grpc sample code found in

examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc

and  

examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_client2.cc.  

So, if you could point out where in this code they are waiting for the result of the Finish, I'd be very grateful.